# dB scale not starting at zero for FFT amplitude

Tags: r, fft

I am trying to do fft on accelerometer data. However when I plot amplitude (in db) vs frequency, the db scale does not start at zero. It starts at 20 and goes till -80. I think I am following all the steps the way they are supposed to.

1. Zero-padding the signal to the next higher power of 2 (if required)
2. Applying the window function
3. Taking the FFT
4. Converting double-sided FFT output into single-sided output through scaling
5. Applying the window correction factor (coherent gain)
6. Finding the signal amplitude - both absolute and db

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? My entire code is given below.

```
library(signal)
library(pracma)

signal_in <- pz$ACC[1:1000]
fs <- 5000
zero_padding <- FALSE
windowfn <- "rectangle"
demean <- FALSE
detrend <- FALSE

# Length of the signal

L <- length(signal_in)

# Removing the trend or mean as required

if (detrend == TRUE) {
    signal_in <- detrend(signal_in, "linear")
} else if (demean == TRUE) {
    signal_in <- detrend(signal_in, "constant")
}

# Various window functions

if (windowfn == "hanning") {
    window_coeff <- hanning(L)
    amp_correction_factor <- mean(window_coeff)
} else if (windowfn == "hamming") {
    window_coeff <- hamming(L)
    amp_correction_factor <- mean(window_coeff)
} else if (windowfn == "flattop") {
    window_coeff <- flattopwin(L, "symmetric")
    amp_correction_factor <- mean(window_coeff)
} else if (windowfn == "rectangle") {
    window_coeff <- rep(1, L)
    amp_correction_factor <- mean(window_coeff)
}

# Apply the window function and if required, zero padding
# L is the length of the original signal
# N is the length of the transformed signal or the number of points in the FFT (to the next higher power of 2)

if (zero_padding == TRUE) {

    N <- 2^nextpow2(L)

    if (L < N) {
        zero_pad <- rep(0, (N - L))
        signal_in_w <- signal_in * window_coeff
        signal_in_w <- c(signal_in_w, zero_pad)
    } else if (L == N) {
        signal_in_w <- signal_in * window_coeff
        N <- L
    }

} else {

    if (L %% 2 != 0) {
        signal_in_w <- signal_in * window_coeff
        signal_in_w <- c(signal_in_w, 0)
        N <- L + 1
    } else {
        signal_in_w <- signal_in * window_coeff
        N <- L
    }

}

# Double-sided FFT

signal.fft <- fft(signal_in_w)

# Single-sided FFT with normalisation - signal amplitude (absolute)

signal.amp.abs <- (2/L) * Mod(signal.fft[1:(length(signal.fft)/2)])

# the DC component should not be doubled so halving it

signal.amp.abs[1] <- signal.amp.abs[1] / 2

# window scaling (coherent gain)

signal.amp.abs <- signal.amp.abs / amp_correction_factor

# signal amplitude (dB)

signal.amp.db <- 20*log10(signal.amp.abs)

# Frequency vector

signal.freq <- seq(from = 0, to = fs/2, length.out = length(signal.fft)/2)

# Plot signal amplitude (absolute) vs frequency (Hz)

plot(signal.amp.abs ~ signal.freq, t = "l")

# Plot signal amplitude (dB) vs frequency (Hz)

plot(signal.amp.db ~ signal.freq, t = "l")
```

Is my calculation correct for finding amplitude in db?

Comment: Since `dB` is a *ratio* (it's always relative to something) then it doesn't really matter what the absolute values are - you can just apply whatever offset you want to get the required range.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I have normalized the absolute amplitude values by the max value and then converted those into dB. So now every amplitude value is relative to the max value. This makes the dB scale to start at zero. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Ideally you want 0 dB to be some sort of meaningful reference. In the absence of any sort of calibration you might want to make it correspond to full scale, i.e. if you input a maximum amplitude sine wave (-32767 to +32767 range assuming 16 bit audio) then the reported amplitude for that peak would be 0 dB. Of course if you support different window types then you may want to correct for each of those too.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Let me figure out now what you have suggested.